# Hypersurfaces in Schwarzchild Spacetime

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

The Schwarzschild Spacetime metric is  is given by :

$\text ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)dt^2+\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2)$

I am currently studying doing an extra project for an introductory GR course, I was reading the book by Eric Poisson "A Relativist's Toolkit: The Mathematics of Black-Hole Mechanics".

And I am trying to solve exercise 1 of Chapter 3.

> It asks us to consider a hypersurface  $T = constant$ in Schwarzschild   Spacetime, where 
>   $$T = t + 4M \Bigg[ \sqrt{\frac{r}{2M}} + {\frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg( \frac{\sqrt{\frac{r}{2M}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{r}{2M}}+1}   \Bigg) }     \Bigg] .$$ 
>   Use as (r,$\theta$,$\phi$) as coordinates on the hypersurface.
>
> a) Calculate the unit normal $n_{\alpha}$ and find the parametric equations describing the hypersurface.

I am having problem starting as I want to use the equation defined in the book 
as 3.1.4, which is

$n_{\alpha} = \frac{\xi\Phi_{;\alpha}}{\mid g^{\mu\nu}\Phi_{;\mu} \Phi_{;\nu}       \mid^{\frac{1}{2}} }$

but I am not sure if my hypersurface, here denoted by $\xi$ is timelike or spacelike. I have read the introduction but I am not understanding how could I compute it.

Please note $\xi$ is given in eq. 3.1.3 as

$n^{\alpha}n_{\alpha} =\xi =  \Bigg\{  \pm $ 1 if $\sum$ (the hypersurface is timelike (+1) or spacelike (-1))

**EDIT :**
I have determine the unit normal and determined the hypersurface to be spacelike.

I am struggling now to determine the parametric equations. Can I use $x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y = r\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $z =r\cos\theta$ ? 
I am not sure how can I use the normal vector though to calculate the tangent vectors

Comment: The unit normal is a vector of the tangent space at $\alpha$ which is orthogonal to the tangent space of the surface (orthogonal for the bilinear form $g_\alpha$ coming form the metric, a quadratic form on $T_\alpha M =  \mathbb{R}dt+ \mathbb{R}dr + \mathbb{R}d\phi + \mathbb{R}d\theta $) ?

Comment: @reuns OK I have determined now the unit normal. Still not sure how could I determine the parametric equations. I have edited my question. Thanks